# Iphone Internet Connection Verification - Reachability

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, internet-connection

I read there were many problem with the Reachability sample app that apple provided, but now with their new 2.2 implementation it's suppose to work fine.

So I just want an advice before I integrate it into my app instead of my current implementation.

Basically I'm asking 2 question:

1. Will this code work ? I need to know if internet is available through 3G or WIFI. (If there is a WIFI with no internet, of course I need it to return false)

2.I'm planning to deploy my app on ios 3.0 and above, do I need to perform any adjustments so it won't crash on ios below 4.0 (cause Reachability 2.2 said to be working on ios 4) ?

Thanks alot!!

```
+ (BOOL) isInternetReachable
{
    NetworkStatus status = [[Util sharedReachability] currentReachabilityStatus];

    return (status != NotReachable);
}

+ (Reachability*) sharedReachability
{
    if (reachability == nil)
    {
        reachability = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] retain];   
        [reachability startNotifier];
    }
    return reachability;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this code is gonna work. It is right.

Comment: How do you know ? Please provide information if you want me to accept the answer. Did you work with it on ios prior to 4 ?

Comment: Yes I used for the same. In one of my application i need to check the internet reachability.